# multiple tangent lines to a plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Suppose that $C=V(F)$, with $F\in k[X,Y]$ ($k$ algebraically closed), is an irreducible plane curve such that $P=(0,0)$ is a nodal singular point (or an ordinary multiple point according to Fulton's book) of multiplicity $m\ge 2$. A procedure to find exactly $m$ distinct tangent lines at $P$ is the following:

---

If $F_m$ is the homogeneous part of degree $m$ of $F$, we factorize it in exactly $m$ linear terms:
$$F_m=\lambda\prod_{i=1}^m(X-\alpha_iY)\quad\quad  \lambda,\alpha_i\in k$$
Now each $X-\alpha_iY=0$ is a tangent line in $P$.

---

I don't understand the geometrical meaning of the above procedure. Why by considering the factorization of the homogeneous part of degree $m$ we obtain tangent lines? If $P$ is a non-singular point, the tangent line in $P$ is "justified" by the differential calculus, in fact  the gradient of $F$  is a tangent vector in $P$ and it spans the tangent line. So when all partial derivatives vanish in $P$, where is the geometrical/analytic insight?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like to think about it this way. If $F = 0$, and $F = F_m$ + higher order terms near $(0,0)$, the higher order terms go to 0 faster than $F_m$, so the graph should look approximately like $F_m = 0$ near $(0,0)$, and $F_m = 0$ = union of $m$ tangent lines. If you try to look at the graphs of some polynomials this point maybe clearer: for example $y^2 = x^2+x^3$ or $y^2 = x^2 + x^5+y^6+x^7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k=\mathbb{C}.$ I think, the best intuitive explanation is related to the notion of "*tangent cone*" (See [Gathmann's notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf) page 61) which is the "best" approximation of $C$ around a singularity.

You know that the linear part of $F$ is the simplest approximation of $C$ around $P,$ so in the absence of the linear part (singularity), we should stick to the second option which is the non-zero homogeneous part $F_m$ of $F$ with the *smallest degree* in the homogeneous decomposition of $F.$ (for example, let $F(X,Y)=(Y^2-X^2)-X^3$ then $F_0=F_1=0,$ $F_2=Y^2-X^2$ and $F_3=-X^3.$)

The affine algebraic set generated by the ideal $(F_m)$ forms a cone over the singularity $P$ and is called the tangent cone. (in the above example, it is $V(Y^2-X^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ which contains two tangent lines $Y=\pm X$ of $C$ at $P.$) Then, if $F_m$ factorizes into linear products $\lambda\prod_{i=1}^m(X-\alpha_iY)$ the affine zero locus is the tangent cone at $P$ contianing $m$ tangent lines of $C$ at $P.$ Of course, since $\alpha_i$'s may not be distinct in general, you may have a sort of thickened tanget lines (for example, $F(X,Y)=Y^3-X^2$ then $F_2=-X^2$ and $V(X^2)$ is the thickened $x$-axis.)

Furthermore, the *projectivized tangent cone* i.e. $V_p(F_m)$ where $V_p(I)$ is the projective zero locus of $I$ is the *exceptional locus* in the blowup of $C$ at $P.$ (in our example, then the exceptional locus of $\tilde{C}$ the blowup of $C$ at $P,$ has two points corresponding to two tangent lines $Y=\pm X.$ )

Comment: For $k[X,Y]$, the tangent cone is always union of lines, is it right? One can always factor a form in linear terms (maybe not distinct)

Comment: I set $k=\mathbb{C}$ to settle the issue partly. The answer is no for general $k.$ For example, take $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $F(X,Y)=X^2+Y^2-X^3$ then $F_2=X^2+Y^2$ doesn't factor into linear product.